# Store enum name, not value in database using EBean

Tags: enums, playframework-2.0, ebean

I have this enum :

```
public enum DocumentTypes {
    PDF("PDF Document"), JPG("Image files (JPG)"), DOC("Microsoft Word documents");

    private final String displayName;

    DocumentTypes(final String display) {
        this.displayName = display;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return this.displayName;
    }
}
```

And a model like this :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "documents")
public class Document extends Model {
    @Id
    public Long id;
    
    @Constraints.Required
    @Formats.NonEmpty
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Column(length=20, nullable=false)
    public DocumentTypes type;

    @Constraints.Required
    @Formats.NonEmpty
    @Column(nullable=false)
    public String document;
}
```

I match the enum using this in my controller :

```
DynamicForm form = form().bindFromRequest();
// ...
Document doc = new Document();
doc.type = DocumentTypes.valueOf(form.field("type").value());
doc.save();
```

The problem is that in database, it's stored as "Microsoft Word documents", but I would prefer to store it as DOC.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can define it very fine granular with the Anotation [EnumMapping](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/annotation/EnumMapping.html) or [EnumValue](http://www.avaje.org/static/javadoc/pub/com/avaje/ebean/annotation/EnumValue.html). This works with the old version org.avaje.ebean.

It seems that there was a complete rewrite of the code. In the actual version there is a different [approach](http://ebean-orm.github.io/docs/mapping/extension/dbenumvalue).

Comment: Both links are dead now, can you add some description to this?